# Which OS would you advise to set up a react native environement?

Tags: cross-platform, react

*I'd like to set, first time, on my PC an environement where i could do react native coding.
It runs windows 10,  but it can run too linux/android as virtual machines .*

**Q:** Which OS will the better to install the tools needed to keep a stable environment in the futur or does it make no difference?

*I'll be starting from there https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup .*

Comment: Pretty much any supported OS will do, given the only constraint of "react native coding". Focus on which tools you want instead, and then they may give some more clue, or just leave it to your preference.

Comment: @Alejandro okay, then i'll go for a start with win and then find out what i'll be missing. I cannot clarify that part yet :( . I need to bake that cake first.